# Java String Split: "Ignore" A Split Parameter

Tags: java

I'm trying to split a string every time there is a comma in it.

```
    String myString = "\"Shire, Middle Earth\",Hobbits, J.R.R Tolkien";
```

My string, when printed out is: "Shire, Middle Earth",Hobbits, J.R.R. Tolkien

Notice that there is a space between Shire and Middle Earth

When I do the following...

```
    String[] myString = line.split(",");
```

It counts the comma between the Shire and Middle Earth as a comma to split the data a (as it should). How can I get it to "ignore" that comma?

Comment: Simply put, never use a delimiter that might occur within your data.  If there is a chance that a comma might appear within a token, then don't use a comma to separate tokens.

Comment: Unfortunately, my string is coming from a file that uses commas to separate the data :'(  I would definitely use a different delimeter if it were possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
line.split(",(?!\\s)")
```

This is lookahead in regex. You can see this link [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)